# Node and Passport Cannot Get Password to change with user.setPassword

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

So, I am trying to setup my program to update a user's password once the old one is confirmed correct.  I have gotten all but one line of this code to function the way I expect it to:

```
router.put("/:id/edit_password", isLoggedIn, isAdministrator, async function(req, res){ 
    user = {};
    try {
        user = await User.findById(req.params.id)
    }
    catch (err) {console.log(err);} 

    user.authenticate(req.body.user["old_password"], async function(err, model, passwordError){
        if(passwordError){
            console.log("Old Password is Incorrect");
            // Flash Old Password is Incorrect
            res.redirect("/users/" + req.params.id + "/edit_password");
        } else if (model) {
            console.log("Old Password is Correct");
            try {
                await user.setPassword(req.body.user["new_password"]);  //this line does not work
                console.log("Password Changed");
            }
            catch (err) {console.log(err);} 
            res.redirect("/users/" + req.params.id);
        } else
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

The await user.setPassword part of this does not seem to function.  With the console.logs, I can confirm that everything is going the way it should.  Is there a different function that needs to be used besides user.setPassword in this case?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if your schema is more or less set like this 
  `user{ //...somedate,password{type:string,..} }` you shouldset your new password like this `user.Password=req.body.new_password`

```
if you want to use passport setPassword 
 user.setPassword(req.body.new_password, function(err,user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
           console.log("the password changed for this "+user)
        }
    })
```

Comment: I was trying to use the user.setPassword, because I thought that was part of passport; I am trying to make sure that I set it using Passport's hashing method, that is why I didn't just store the password itself in the schema.

Comment: can you try the code i updated and tell me if it worked

Comment: I refactored my code to what you wrote here and unfortunately, this still did not seem to work.  The "console.log("the password changed for this "+user)" showed up in my console as expected, but the password did not change for the user somehow.

Comment: I consoled.logged(req.body.user["new_password"]) as well, and can confirm that the new password string is what I am expecting it to be, so that part is fine.  Its really the setPassword function that seems to refuse to work.

Comment: Hey, I got it working finally using a different function, but thank you so much for taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 0):

So, this will not explain why setPassword did not work, but I did find out a way to get this working a different way.  Instead of using setPassword(req.body.user["new_password"]), instead, I used the passport function: changePassword(req.body.user["old_password"], req.body.user["new_password"]) and this worked.  The documentation I used is here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nodejs-authentication-using-passportjs-and-passport-local-mongoose/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Adding the `save()` worked for me.  Without the `await user.save()`, the password did not seem to work.

```
await user.setPassword(req.body.password, async function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        await user.save() ;
        console.log("Password Updated!");
    }
});
```